# Regex to find end of paragrphs

Tags: regex

I'm parsing text and the paragraph breaks have been removed.   I need a regex to locate any sentence that ends in a punctuation (period, question, etc) and there is no space before the next sentence starts.  I then take that and insert two linebreaks.  Unfortunately the Regex I have so far is too greedy and is snagging on URLs.

```
preg_replace('/(?<!\.)\.(?!(\s|$|\,|\w\.))/', '.<br/><br/> ', $string);
```

Example text:

> Approved source is xxxx xxx.The solicitation is an XXX and will be available at the link provided in this notice. See http://www.mysite.com. Hard copies of this solicitation are not available. Specifications, plans, or drawings are not available.All responsible sources may submit a quote which, if timely received, shall be considered.Quotes must be submitted electronically.
>
> Final Desired Result:
>
> Approved source is xxx xxxx.
>
> The solicitation is an XXX and will be available at the link provided in this notice. Hard copies of this solicitation are not available.  See http://www.mysite.com.  Specifications, plans, or drawings are not available.
>
> All responsible sources may submit a quote which, if timely received, shall be considered.
>
> Quotes must be submitted electronically.
>
> Thanks

Comment: Can you describe in words how to tell the difference between the two?  You might be able to come up with something, but you need a concrete way of knowing the difference.  Is it if it starts with `http`?

Answer (score 0):

`(?<!w{3})[\.\?](?=\S)(?!com)`

Assuming that all your `URL`s will start/end with `www.` and `.com`, this will prevent it from matching, while retaining a match on all `.` and `?` that have non-whitespace after them. You'll have to replace your match as `.<br><br>` though, not just `<br><br>`.

[Play with the regex here](http://regexr.com?31ffa).

Comment: All URLs don't start with "WWW" but they seem to start with "http"